# What is the proper way to create a file in your server after the application starts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

So I'm trying to do a simple web-app using the default stuff (Tomcat, no framework).

What I want is after I start server, I want my application to create a "Sample.txt" file in my server using a "SetUpDataService.class". Is there a way to do that?

Im thinking creating a "SetUpServlet" without mapping and just call the "SetUpDataService.class" in the init method, but it looks so dirty and feels wrong.

What is the best way for that using the default stuff?
And is there a library exists for that purpose? Currently im not using any 3rd party library to strengthen my core understanding of JavaEE.

PS. I dont know if this question exists.I just cant find the right keyword so I posted this question.

EDIT: How about creating initial data on database? Is the approach OK?

Comment: Why do you need that file ? What do you mean by initial data on database?

Comment: Just want to create a file, it has no purpose for now. About the initial data on database, I mean like I want to have predetermined data in a table that was inserted by a service-class (running a script, etc) that was ran after the application started.

Comment: @JBNizet - I just want to know what is the best way for that, its not about what is used for. I want to know it for the sake of learning the best practice.

Comment: The best practice is, most probably, to not create that file at runtime, when the application starts, but to include it in the webapp, at build time. We could give better advice if you told why you want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for knowledge if you wanted to do that, you can achieve that using `ServletContextListener` as shown below. `contextInitialized()` method will be called by the container during startup (i.e., when the `servletcontext` object is being created).

```
    @WebListener
    public class MyProjectListener implements ServletContextListener {

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            //add your file creation code here
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            //add code cleanup the resources
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, question was just for the knowledge. "Listener" keyword was a no-brainer, i feel so dumb, lol.